# Scala: How to return column name and value from a dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, row

I am trying to create a function which can scan a dataframe row by row and, for each row, spit out the non empty columns and the column names. But the challenge is that I dont know the number of columns or their names in the input dataframe.

A function something like `GetNotEmptyCols(InputRow: Row): (Colname:String, ColValue:String)`

As sample data, consider the following dataframes.

```
val DataFrameA = Seq(("tot","","ink"), ("yes","yes",""), ("","","many")).toDF("ColA","ColB","ColC")
val DataFrameB = Seq(("yes",""), ("","")).toDF("ColD","ColE")
```

I have been trying to get the column value for each row object but dont know how to do that when I dont have the names of columns. I could extract the column names from the dataframe and pass it to the function as an additional variable but am hoping for a better approach since row object should have the column names and I should be able to extract them.

The output I am working to get is something like this:

```
DataFrameA.foreach{ row => GetNotEmptyCols(row)} gives output 

For row1: ("ColA", "tot"), ("ColC", "ink")
For row2: ("ColA","yes"),("ColB","yes")
For row3: ("ColC","many")

DataFrameB.foreach{ row => GetNotEmptyCols(row)} gives output
For row1: ("ColD", "yes")
For row2: ()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by myself. I can use getValueMap method to create a map of column names and the values which i can return and then convert it to a list.

```
  def returnNotEmptyCols(inputRow: Row): Map[String,String] = {
    val colValues = inputRow.getValuesMap[String](inputRow.schema.fieldNames)
    .filter(x => x._2!= null && x._2!= "")
    colValues
  }

returnNotEmptyCols(rowA1).map{case(k,v) => (k, v)}toList
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find below my implementation for GetNonEmptyCols, which takes **row** along with **columns** -

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SparkSession}
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

object StackoverFlowProblem {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Test").master("local").getOrCreate()

    import spark.sqlContext.implicits._

    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

    val DataFrameA = Seq(("tot","","ink"), ("yes","yes",""), ("","","many")).toDF("ColA","ColB","ColC")
    val DataFrameB = Seq(("yes",""), ("","")).toDF("ColD","ColE")

    //Store column names in a variable, append to-be-added column 'index' as well
    val columns = DataFrameA.columns :+ "index"

    //Use monotonically_increasing_id() API to add row indices in the dataframe
    DataFrameA.withColumn("index",monotonically_increasing_id()).foreach(a => GetNotEmptyCols(a,columns))

  }

  def GetNotEmptyCols(inputRow: Row, columns:Array[String]): Unit ={

    val rowIndex = inputRow.getAs[Long]("index")
    val a = inputRow.length
    val nonEmptyCols = ArrayBuffer[(String,String)]()


    for(i <- 0 until a-1){

      val value = inputRow.getAs[String](i)
      if(!value.isEmpty){
        val name = columns(i)
        nonEmptyCols += Tuple2(name,value)
      }

    }

    println(s"For row $rowIndex: " + nonEmptyCols.mkString(","))

  }

}
```

This will print the below output for your first Dataframe(I have used zero-based indexing for row printing) -

```
For row 0: (ColA,tot),(ColC,ink)
For row 1: (ColA,yes),(ColB,yes)
For row 2: (ColC,many)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.